# Ionic - Stop spinner after page is loaded

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have a simple button with spinner inside

```
<button class=" mybutton " ng-click="click()" id="servieren" ui-sref="menu.servieren"><ion-spinner ng-hide="showing" class="spinner-spiral"></ion-spinner>Servieren</button>
```

and when i click on the button the spinner starts spinning and page opens, all fine.

This is js code inside controllers.js

```
.controller('inhaltCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showing = true;
    $scope.click = function(){
        $scope.showing = false;
    }
})
```

BUT when i go back to page where the button is, the spinner is still spinning and it eats out the cpu. How to stop the spinner once the page is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved [with](https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-lifecycle-events/) [View LifeCycle and Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

- `ionViewDidLoad`: Fired **only when a view is stored in memory**. This event is NOT fired on entering a view that is already cached. It’s a nice place for init related tasks.
- `ionViewWillEnter`: It’s fired when entering a page, **before it becomes the active** one. Use it for tasks you want to do every time you enter in the view (setting event listeners, updating a table, etc.).
- `ionViewDidEnter`: Fired when entering a page, **after it becomes the active page**. Quite similar to the previous one.
- `ionViewWillLeave`: Fired when you leave a page, **before it stops being the active** one. Use it for things you need to run every time you are leaving a page (deactivate event listeners, etc.).
- `ionViewDidLeave`: Fired when you leave a page, **after it stops being the active** one. Similar to the previous one.
- `ionViewWillUnload`: Fired **when a view is going to be completely removed** (after leaving a non-cached view).

Comment: Imam, ali ne mogu na chat jer "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here."

Comment: sad mozes na chat :) imas preko 20 reputation